# NodeJS and PassportJS - Session lost

Tags: node.js, session, mobile, passport.js

At the moment Im writing a mobile html client which trys to login on a NodeJS Server over a local authentication provided by Passport JS. I got two cases, one works, one fails. Here are parts of my code first.

Client does the login like that:

```
Authentication.logIn(user).
    success(function(data){
        console.log("success log in");

    // HERE I MAKE A CALL TO THE PROJECT RESOURCE


    });
```

Client Factory Method:

```
logIn: function logIn(user) {
  return $http.post(baseURL + "/login" + "?name=" + user.name + "&password=" + user.password, {});
}
```

NodeJS Server with passport

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {     passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {

    if (err || !user) {
        return res.json(403, {error: "login failed"});
    }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(403, {error: "login failed"});
        }

        var response = {
            status  : 200,
            success : 'Logged In Successfully'
        }

        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
})(req, res, next);
```

Passport Config:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
logger.info("Passport Login serializeUser");

done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
logger.info("Passport Login deserializeUser");

User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
});
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(req, name, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); //     req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

Node JS Routes (part of):

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    res.redirect('/init');
}

app.get("/projects", isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    // do something
});
```

The main case is:

Client makes a http post with username and password onto the node js server. There we log in through passport js locally. In one case it works.

Case 1(works):

I go to localhost:3001/projects. It gets redirected to /init because Im not logged in. I make a post with username and password to the node server. After that I can get the projects json through localhost:3001/projects.

Case2(doesnt work!):

Now on the client. I make a http post with username and password onto the node server, I can log in, no errors. After that I make a http get to /projects, nut now I cant reach it, because the req.isAuthenticated() in the isLoggedIn function returns false. I kinda lost the passport session, right?

Can someone explain my why my session disappears or how I can probably find out what the exact problem is?

Br, Andy